# Texts on Coxeter groups

Tags: reference-request, big-list, advice, book-recommendation, coxeter-groups

I'm looking for an introductory text on Coxeter groups. It can assume undegraduate knowledge of Algebra (Groups up to and including the Sylow theorems in Fraleigh, elementary knowledge of rings, integral domains and fields). It may be expository papers or full books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A classical reference is [Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups](http://books.google.at/books/about/Reflection_Groups_and_Coxeter_Groups.html?id=ODfjmOeNLMUC&redir_esc=y) by James Humphreys. The book is self-contained, and only assumes some knowledge of algebra.

Comment: I can also recommend that book.

Comment: Yes, upon second thought, the name "Humphreys" has come up almost exclusively when I have tried to talk about Coxeter groups with faculty.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent book is [Lie Groups and Lie Algebras, Chapters 4-6](https://books.google.com.na/books?id=2CSYFcgAlRMC&printsec=copyright#v=onepage&q&f=false) by N. Bourbaki, from the collection Elements of Mathematics. This is very readable and friendly compared to other Bourbaki books. I believe it is the best book in the whole series Elements of Mathematics.